# Are some touch events skipped (not delivered to my root view) by Android when UI thread is busy?

Tags: android, multithreading

When I swipe on my view I see that there is a series of touch events delivered to it: ACTION_DOWN, multiple ACTION_MOVE and then ACTION_UP. When I print those action event codes it looks like 0222222222222222222222222222222222222222221, where 0 - DOWN, 2 - MOVE, 1 - UP.

I noticed that when I do this swipe when my UI thread is busy, the number of touch events I receive is much smaller, instead of 0222222222222222222222222222222222222222221 I get just 021 or 0221 for example, so only one or two ACTION_MOVE events instead of more than ten, in spite of my finger swiping the same way.

Does Android throttle ACTION_MOVE when it sees that UI thread is busy? I would understand if they were delivered with a delay, but I expect all of them being delivered, and definitely most of them are just never delivered.

I know that the UI thread should not be busy, long running operations should be run into the background thread etc, but this is not a point of my question.

Comment: oh, this happens on Samsung S6

Answer (score 0):

It occurred those ACTION_MOVE events are hidden in historical tables of the one ACTION_MOVE that is delivered to my view - it is by design optimization of Android API, I guess this is what Android does to speed things up when UI thread utilization is high. Check "Batching" section of https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

After converting historical tables to MotionEvents and passing them to fling gesture detector my swipe works like a charm :D